# Why can't I define two member pointers that are the same type of the class in the same row

Tags: c++

This code generates error like below

> error: field 'next' has incomplete type 'Node'

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node(int k, int v) {
            key = k;
            val = v;
        }
    public:
        Node* prev, next;
        int key, val;
};
```

Change Node* to int won't have the same complain. Put prev and next into separate lines solves the error.

Why can't I define two member pointers that are the same type of the class in the same row?

Comment: Use `*` on both variables: `Node *prev, *next;`. This is because `*` qualifier only applies to the first variable `prev`.

Comment: That's one reason to put the star to the variable. `Node *prev, next;` is more obvious.

Comment: A good way to not mess up is to put each variable declaration on separate lines. or put the * next to the variable name so Node *prev, *next. You will be less likely to miss it. Coding is not a contest of how short you can make it, so space it out, comment and put breaks in logic like a book has paragraphs.. You will have a better time reading it in 6 months when you have forgotten what you were doing.

Comment: That (among other reasons) is why it is a bad habit to define multiple variables on one line.

Comment: Hi there @Raxvan. Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit indeed not a great practice, however elaborating a proper answer (like yours) requires time i don't always have. Sometimes it happens that no one gives any answer so at least a small comment can help the question, or others formulate a more proper reply.

Comment: @Raxvan: Providing an answer in the comments section is double un-good. It bypasses all our peer review measures. If you don't have time to write an answer right now, that's fine! Somebody else will be able to do it instead. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Placement of the asterisk in pointer declarations](/q/180401/90527)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asterisk (*) belongs with the variable name.  `Node` is the datatype.  In effect, you've defined:

```
Node *prev;
Node next;
```

Add an asterisk in front of `next`, e.g. `*next`.

The error relates to the fact that in doing so, you've failed to initialise the instance of `Node` stored in `next`.  `prev` is a pointer and doesn't need to be initialised.

Answer (score 2):

You can, you have to do following:

```
Node* prev,* next;
```

People usually get confused by this notation:

```
Node* prev, next;
```

Thinking they declared 2 pointers, but instead they declared a pointer `* next` and instance of a node, and thinking that this is the same as

```
Node* prev;
Node* next;
```

but it is not, it is the same as

```
Node* prev;
Node next;
```

I would suggest using

```
Node *prev, *next;
```

and always remember that for every pointer declared you need `*` in front of it.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is good practice to write `Node* prev`, with the asterisk aligned to the left, a multi-variable declaration is the one edge case exposing the fact that the C++ grammar (largely inherited from C) doesn't see it that way. It "binds" the `*` to the name, not to the type, so it "looks like" `Node *prev` internally.

As a consequence, you have actually created:

```
Node* prev;
Node  next;
```

… the second declaration being impossible as you're inside the `Node` definition.

You could fix it this way:

```
Node *prev, *next;
```

Or this way:

```
Node* prev, *next;
```

But the latter is internally inconsistent in style, and the former is inconsistent with a left-alignment used elsewhere in your code. Of course you could start right-aligning your asterisks everywhere to re-introduce consistency, but that has many more downsides that aren't worth it for this one edge case.

What I think you *really* should do is just split the declaration into two:

```
Node* prev;
Node* next;
```

This is arguably neater anyway.

Comment: I realise there are already answers saying much of this, but I did just want to put a slightly different spin on it (and on the suggested solution) for a complete set of pictures the OP can choose from.

Comment: I think it’s subjective if it’s good practice, and why teach someone a style that doesn’t meet the requirement of the languages parser?

Comment: @DaveMeehan: _"subjective"_ Absolutely (& I did use words like "I think"!) _"meet the requirement"_ This edge case that you shouldn't be doing anyway (ok plus ridiculous nested cdecls) is the only one where you'll even notice it. Not a "requirement" really. Conversely, parser aside, the `*` _is_ part of the type! So let's follow the logical/semantic meaning instead of an "implementation detail" that won't even hit us if we write clean code. I touched on this in an ancient blog post: http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/